# AngularJS IE9 Crash due to Add-On

Tags: angularjs, crash, internet-explorer-9, ieaddon

After getting my IE9 install to be caught up to the user's IE9 KB version I then had her run "Internet Explorer (No Add-ins)".  Search windows for "Internet Explorer" and you should see it.
If your web site works then you know it was a rogue add-in crashing IE.
Then it's trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling the Onbase "OBXPopupBlockerAssistant" resolved the issue.